# Can Magento use a session variable in a cache key?

Tags: php, caching, magento

I'm running a split A-B test on a couple of homepage layouts. There's an observer that sets up the session variable (group A or group B) and then the layout changes based on that variable.

The problem is that the page is caching (in the Magento full-page cache) and no matter what group the user is in, they are all seeing either the A page or B page.

Can I modify Magento so that each version of the homepage caches seperately? Or can I disable caching entirely on the homepage? Or is there a better way to do this kind of test?

Comment: You should implement full page cache hole punching for your block. See this tutorial [this tutorial](http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/10160075026/ee-full-page-cache-hole-punching) and [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126548/trying-get-dynamic-content-hole-punched-through-magentos-full-page-cache).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly apply, but I had to cache the footer differently depending on which page it was on, and ended up editing the `Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php` file and changing the `getCacheKey()` function by adding part of the url to the returned variable. Could you not append the session variable instead?

I understand you are not looking at the footer as I was, but it seemed like it might point you in a helpful direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTTP 1.1 compliant header to alter the caching behaviours for the specific page.

See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.6

The header you require is `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

You need to send that header out with the document. Using php, you would use the header function to specify headers.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question. It's the internal Magento cache that's being problematic, not the browser cache.